# How to delete lines in file1 if comumn

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with 4 columns and i need to delete from file1 if column 3 is in files 2

Example:

File1:

```
14769,marty.------@googlemail.com,c076a7b6a52857ddf2f2e60d71dda6bf,49
14770,maryfi-------@googlemail.com,23fc2887a3a8248ddea570b5700b1708,49
14771,n.s------@googlemail.com,e504a6617f375ce04f4e51f1ec66dd93,49
14772,paula------@googlemail.com,f918f5b8df1d6285892d003c2fb9e3cf,49
14773,pkec.------@googlemail.com,4ca2c5d670f324c31a20854873bf63ac,49
14774,squi-------@googlemail.com,d26a0296a361b79afd98ede1af918f6d,49
```

File 2:

```
d26a0296a361b79afd98ede1af918f6d
4ca2c5d670f324c31a20854873bf63ac
```

so result will be like this

```
14769,marty.------@googlemail.com,c076a7b6a52857ddf2f2e60d71dda6bf,49
14770,maryfi-------@googlemail.com,23fc2887a3a8248ddea570b5700b1708,49
14771,n.s------@googlemail.com,e504a6617f375ce04f4e51f1ec66dd93,49
14772,paula------@googlemail.com,f918f5b8df1d6285892d003c2fb9e3cf,49
```

i have tried with this

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3 ;next} !($3 in a) {print }' OFS='\t' file1 file2
```

but not working

Comment: I'm here for the PHP tag?

Comment: `grep -vf file2 file1`?

Comment: thanks cyrus , it worked but it took a long time for large files.

Comment: Scuzzy not for php for Linux command

Comment: `grep` is as fast as any other solution likely to be offered. Good luck.

Comment: This might help: use a faster CPU or split file1 and use with multiple `grep`s multiple CPUs/Cores.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment not enough rep; but I've tried your code with `gawk` and it did remove the two lines as you wanted. The reason you don't get tab delimited output is that OFS takes effect only after $0 is rebuilt, so you can force this by simple assignment like $1=$1 and your OFS='\t':

```
 {a[$1]=$3 ;next} !($3 in a) {$1=$1; print}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
```

Result:

`14769  marty.------@googlemail.com c076a7b6a52857ddf2f2e60d71dda6bf    49
14770   maryfi-------@googlemail.com    23fc2887a3a8248ddea570b5700b1708    49
14771   n.s------@googlemail.com    e504a6617f375ce04f4e51f1ec66dd93    49
14772   paula------@googlemail.com  f918f5b8df1d6285892d003c2fb9e3cf    49`